# Strange math notation, vertical bar with parentheses.

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, notation

So I was reading "Resistance Distance" (D. J. Klein, M. Randić) (Journal of Mathematical Chemistry 12(1993)81-95) when I came up with strange notation.

From the paper:

The graph adjacency matrix is defined as:
$$A_{xy} = (x|A|y) =  \begin{cases} 1/r_{xy} & x \sim y \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}$$

The graph degree matrix of a graph is defined as:

$$\Delta_{xy} = (x|\Delta|y) = \delta(x,y) \sum_{z}^{\sim x} 1/r_{xy}$$

$$ |\phi) \equiv \sum_x |x)  $$

My main question is what does the combination of the vertical bar parentheses mean. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is physicists' notation: "bra"s and "ket"s.

Comment: As mentioned, this is the bra-ket notation, and $(x|A|y)=x^{\top}Ay$

Comment: As a side note, physicists would usually write it $\langle x\vert A\vert y\rangle$.

Comment: Your help was valueable, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a community wiki answer so the question can be closed.

This is [bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra-ket_notation), as commonly used in physics.